# jQuery Plugin Authoring Scoping

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

If I want to have a publicly accessible function on a jQuery plugin I'm making, is this the proper way to do it?

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.myPlug = function(options) {
        // Do this...
        this.hello = function() {
            return 1;
        };
    }
})(jQuery);

var foo = $("div").myPlug();

// then do this...
foo.hello();
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should structure your plugin so that method names can be passed as parameters to your plugin. This is recommended by the [jQuery plugin authoring guide](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring):

```
(function($) {

    var methods = {
        init: function(options) {

        },
        hello: function () {
            return 1;
        }
    };

    $.fn.myPlug = function(method) {
        if (methods[method]) {
            return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
            return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
        } else {
            $.error('Method ' + method + ' does not exist on jQuery.myPlug');
        }
    };

})(jQuery);
```

The usage would go something like this:

```
$("div").myPlug({ ... });
$("div").myPlug("hello"); // returns 1
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason why this is preferable? I saw the docs saying to do it this way, but I couldn't figure out why that was a better way to do it...

Comment: I think the main point is that it's better than using multiple namespaces for one plugin. When you use this method you only take one namespace ("myPlug"). Maybe I misread your question at first though--is your plugin returning an object that you can take actions on?

Comment: Well, in my example I create a member function inside the plugin, and from what I can tell, it's not using more than one namespace in $.fn (right?). I just want to make sure of this... since JS's scoping sometimes eludes me.

Comment: @Ian: I see. I think your pattern is fine, one thing you benefit by following jQuery's recommendation is a familiar API for those using your plugin.